# Toggle animation not working

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm doing a toggle to show a hidden div, like so:

```
jQuery('button').click(function(){
    jQuery("#area").slideToggle(function() {
        jQuery("#menu").animate({ "top": "+=423px" }, "slow" );
    });
});
```

However, I'd like that on the second click, not only the area hides again, but the `#menu` gets up again to its original position. I'm trying to no avail the following code:

```
jQuery('button').click(function(){
    jQuery("#area").slideToggle(function() {
        jQuery("#menu").animate({ "top": "+=423px" }, "slow" );
    },
    function() {
        jQuery("#menu").animate({ "top": "-=423px" }, "slow" );
    });
});
```

...why this won't work?
Many thanks for any input,

Comment: @tymeJV it is valid, see the examples down this page: http://api.jquery.com/animate/, specifically the one moving the blue-grey box left and right.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan -- Well damn, scratch that idea.

Comment: Can you please show your HTML for #area and #menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag for that, for instance checking if the element is hidden, as the display property is toggled

```
jQuery('button').click(function(){
    jQuery("#area").slideToggle(function() {
        var updown = $(this).is(':visible') ? '-=' : '+=';
        jQuery("#menu").stop(true, true).animate({ "top": updown + 423 + 'px' }, "slow" );
    });
});
```

Note that jQuery's slideToggle does not accept two callbacks, only one, there is no built in toggle functionality.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bm92/1/)

Comment: Wow, it's working thanks! I had to reverse the order and code it like this: var updown = $(this).is(':visible') ? '+=' : '-=';. But, why my original code didn't work? The code, strangely enough, was taking into account only the last function ("pull it from the top"). EDIT: ok you explain it in your answer. Thanks :)